# Property not found although it's in the header

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one view and one View Controller. I am trying to have a reference to View Controller from the view.

PlusCalendarView.h

```
@interface PlusCalendarView : TSQCalendarView

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *initialVC;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpCalendarView:self.myCalendarView];

    self.myCalendarView.initialVC = self; // ERROR: Property initialVC not found on object of type "PlusCalendarView"
}
```

How come it cannot find initialVC property?

**Update:**

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <TimesSquare/TimesSquare.h>

@interface PlusCalendarView : TSQCalendarView;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCalendar *calendar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PlusCalendarView *myCalendarView;

@end
```

Comment: One note based on what I'm inferring from your code is that `initialVC` should probably be weak.  Can you show how you declare `myCalendarView`.  There's nothing visibly problematic with the current code.

Comment: Did you `#import PlusCalendarView.h`?

Comment: If I do '#import PlusCalendarView.h' it complains there's a duplication definition. @Logan I updated my question to include ViewController.h

Comment: Do you have two classes named `PlusCalendarView` in your project?

Comment: Why do you declare PlusCalendarView in ViewController.h??

Comment: You shouldn't need that interface in the `ViewController.h` file. Instead do `@class PlusCalendarView;`

Comment: Yea, that's the problem (the duplicate declaration in viewController.h).  Remove that, add @class in the header, then import plusCalendarView.h in the implementation.

Comment: Thank you!! The mystery is solved :) Could someone please post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Logan, you gave the most complete answer in comments. You should post your answer as an actual answer so the OP can accept it. You deserve the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring `PlusCalendarView` in `ViewController.h` AND `PlusCalendarView.h`.  You should remove the `@interface` declaration from `ViewController.h`.

Instead, add `@class PlusCalendarView` in `ViewController.h` then `#import "PlusCalendarView.h"` in `ViewController.m`